# Implementation of JsSIP on actual phone

Tags: javascript, socket.io, webrtc, sip, jssip

I just took a look JsSIP library, and it seems pretty promising except the fact that it has no actual demonstration or code which implements calling actual mobile phone. so is it actually possible to call phone which is in offline mode or in online? here is code on docs

```
var ua = new JsSIP.UA(configuration);

ua.start();

// Register callbacks to desired call events
var eventHandlers = {
   'progress': function(e) {
       console.log('call is in progress');
    },
    'failed': function(e) {
       console.log('call failed with cause: '+ e.data.cause);
    },
    'ended': function(e) {
       console.log('call ended with cause: '+ e.data.cause);
    },
    'confirmed': function(e) {
       console.log('call confirmed');
    }
};

var options = {
 'eventHandlers'    : eventHandlers,
 'mediaConstraints' : { 'audio': true, 'video': true }
};

var session = ua.call('sip:bob@example.com', options);
```

even demo is implementing call within browsers, which is more easily done with WebRTC but i want to call phone. how is that possible, if it is possible in **OFFLINE** mode it would be better

Comment: If you are looking to makes a phone call from browser, then you will have to use freeswitch along with jsSip.

Comment: I only heard about Asterisk but FreeSwitch seems better, is there any demo of implementing call with it?

Answer (score 2):

You need first to look for a PSTN provider that provides you with a SIP account to make calls to phone numbers. That's not free typically. Then you probably want to configure such a SIP account in your SIP server and router calls from JsSIP to the PSTN provider. And deal with accounting and so on. Not something trivial.

Comment: can i see a demo?

Comment: I see AWS provides freeSWITCH servers and it is in N. Virginia, so can i use it in Eastern Russia for example?

Comment: You may ask AWS.